# Wifi and Ethernet Extremely slow on my computer!

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu 20 and my internet is extremely slow.I'm getting 20-25 MBS on both Wi-Fi and Ethernet. Wi-Fi being slightly faster. My network says its cable of higher speeds and on my laptop, I get around 320mbs. Any ideas?

I limited the network IP info below. Let me know if I omitted anything too much or not enough. I'm a noob at this stuff.

```
$ sudo lshw -class network -short && nmcli device status
H/W path         Device      Class       Description
====================================================
/0/100/15/0      wlp2s0      network     RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
/0/100/15.1/0    enp3s0      network     RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet cont
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION                       
wlp2s0  wifi      connected     Wifi
enp3s0  ethernet  disconnected  --                               
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 37902  bytes 52284157 (52.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6503  bytes 616234 (616.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2195  bytes 207226 (207.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2195  bytes 207226 (207.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       
        inet6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 137909  bytes 154850679 (154.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 103697  bytes 81099372 (81.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Poor IPv6 performance?

Check whether it could be an IPv6 related problem. You can disable IPv6 with

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

If this helps, you can try to set IPv4 precedence over IPv6 by uncommenting `#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` in the file `/etc/gai.conf`.

## Power Management?

Look whether turning off wifi power management could be a least the reason for poor wifi performance:

Edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

and set `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2`.

You can check the current power management state with

```
$ iwconfig 2> /dev/null | grep 'Power Management'
```

## Kernel issue?

Some users experience better network performance by using a newer kernel from [the mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).
But please keep in mind that a newer kernel might have other issues (i.e. in combination with proprietary drivers like NVidia) and you have to keep track of updates etc.
There are also scripts to maintain mainline kernels like [`ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh#ubuntu-mainline-kernelsh).

*If* it is fixed with a newer kernel, chances are high, that a bugfix for this issue will be backported for Ubuntu 20.04. So you should find and track this issue. Therefore you could switch to the stable kernel once this issue has been fixed.

**PS:** You can also add the corresponding Launchpad issue to this thread. This way others can track this issue as well.