# After Updated ubuntu 20.04 lts All browsers working slow

Tags: networking, internet, 20.04, browser

After i updated my Ubuntu to 20.04 lts browsers loading too slow.I am also using windows in same computer and same internet not have this specific problem at all. Could anyone know the solution? I am using like this from 1 month.I updated everything and tried possible solutions from here.Couldn't find a solution...

Answer (score 3):

## Poor IPv6 performance?

Check whether it could be an IPv6 related problem. You can disable IPv6 with

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

If this helps, you can try to set IPv4 precedence over IPv6 by uncommenting `#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` in the file `/etc/gai.conf`.

## Power Management?

Look whether turning off wifi power management could be a least the reason for poor wifi performance:

Edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

and set `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2`.

You can check the current power management state with

```
$ iwconfig 2> /dev/null | grep 'Power Management'
```

## Kernel issue?

Some users experience better network performance by using a newer kernel from [the mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).
But please keep in mind that a newer kernel might have other issues (i.e. in combination with proprietary drivers like NVidia) and you have to keep track of updates etc.
There are also scripts to maintain mainline kernels like [`ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh#ubuntu-mainline-kernelsh).

*If* it is fixed with a newer kernel, chances are high, that a bugfix for this issue will be backported for Ubuntu 20.04. So you should find and track this issue. Therefore you could switch to the stable kernel once this issue has been fixed.

**PS:** You can also add the corresponding Launchpad issue to this thread. This way others can track this issue as well.

**PPS:** This could be the same issue as [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230609/wifi-and-ethernet-extremely-slow-on-my-computer/1238564#1238564).

Comment: I have the same issue with Chromium (worst), Firefox, Opera. However, it is not about slow internet. The browsers itself are working not properly. For instance, in Chromium just to open the bookmark folder lasts about 2-3 sec. I use Ethernet. If I follow the advice for IPv6 is it just temporary to check? Bcs. I don't know how to enable it again then.